# Running sudo in a torified shell

Tags: bash, sudo, tor

I am running a torified shell (. torsocks on) and for some reason I am unable to run commands with sudo privileges. I get the following error:
bash: /usr/bin/su: Operation not permitted.

I've tried adding the debian-tor user to the sudo group and can't seem to find anything useful on the internet.

This is using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server Edition and I've also tried it out with the latest stable edition of Kali, both to no avail.

Comment: You've not provided any OS & release details.

Comment: @guiverc Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server Edition?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers (who have better answers). Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our way to help you improve your question. All facts about your system and problem should go in the Question with [edit].  You may click on any of these [edit] links to [edit] your question.